# Make changes to a browser window once another window is closed

Tags: javascript, browser

So, I have a browser window that if you click on a specific button on it, it opens another window next to it, resizes the first window and then puts the new window next to it. This is great, however, I want the first window (the original one) to go to full size when the 2nd one is closed. (Whenever the user closes the 2nd window he/she opened through clicking on the button, the first window should go to full size). Is there a way to do that?

Note: I don't mean there will be a (close) button on the 2nd one, when the user closes the window the normal way by clicking on the (x) is there a way to know that the user did that and maximize the first original window?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has a [`window.onclose`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.onclose) event that does exactly what you want. Unfortunately, it's not part of the standard, so on other browsers, `window.onunload` is your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [onunload](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2008/04/22/dont-let-the-door-hit-you-onunload-and-onbeforeunload/) event in the child window to notify the parent.